# wireless network not working after suspend in kubuntu 17.10

Tags: wireless, kubuntu, network-manager

Every time my laptop sleeps,my wifi cant access network and i should restart the laptop to access Internet.
I tried this solution
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2223566
But it didn't help.

Can anybody fix this issue?